# How to get office 365 outlook's folders name from a mailbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, office365, office365api

I have authenticated for office 365 outlook using passport js

Now I have access token

So I am looking for to get all folders name with their respective folder Id.

I am using [node-outlook](https://github.com/jasonjoh/node-outlook/blob/master/reference/node-outlook.md) library but I am not aware what APIs they have provided get only folders path and folder id.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to get the folder name and folder Id, you can use the following api call:

```
$http.get("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/$select=Id,ChildFolderCount,DisplayName")
```

Since the above api, only returns main folders, I strongly suggest that you also select ChildFolderCount and add a check in the response, if ChildFolderCount>0, then get the subfolders of the parent by the following call:

```
$http.get("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/"+parent.Id+"/childfolders?$top="+parent.ChildFolderCount)
```

where **parent** is the folder with ChildFolderCount>0.

Answer (score 2):

The folder resource has a `DisplayName` property, so that should get what you want. ([Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#folder--mailfolder)).

You can also explore the API over at https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/. For example, I did a GET on `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders`, and this is an example of the result:

```
{
  "Id": "AQMkAGZjYmY1ZTIwLWI1M2UtNGNkYS05MGQyLTQyMgBjYTliODJhNTIALgAAA6Ii1CwFSf1Ai6F6MypimPkBAGTbcv4AqpNHlH0kubDE5QwAAAIBDwAAAA==",
  "DisplayName": "Drafts",
  "ParentFolderId": "AQMkAGZjYmY1ZTIwLWI1M2UtNGNkYS05MGQyLTQyMgBjYTliODJhNTIALgAAA6Ii1CwFSf1Ai6F6MypimPkBAGTbcv4AqpNHlH0kubDE5QwAAAIBCAAAAA==",
  "ChildFolderCount": 0,
  "UnreadItemCount": 2,
  "TotalItemCount": 9
}
```